# Query to find emails from SELECT FROM VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having a problem with a query that *should* only bring back a specific result set, however it's returning all values. Essentially what I'm trying to do is update the email column in one table with the values from a list from another, the inner query works in that I can get the correct first/last names but the outer query returns all emails and I only want the emails from the listed values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT WorkEmail FROM stafftbl WHERE EXISTS  (
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName,LastName -- inner query starts here
FROM assignments
WHERE Email IN  
(SELECT email 
 FROM 
    (VALUES 
    ('josh@myjob.org'),
    ('pete@myjob.org'),
    ('willy@myjob.org'),
    ('linda@myjob.org'),
    ('mary@myjob.org'),
    ('james@myjob.org'),
    ('ahmed@myjob.org'),
    ('horatio@myjob.org'),
    ('luke@myjob.org'),
    ('terri@myjob.org'),
    ('chuck@myjob.org'),
    ('betty@myjob.org'),
    ('bigbob@myjob.org'),
    ('arthur@myjob.org'),
    ('Ajessica@myjob.org') -- there's a lot more than these.
)E(email))                 -- inner query ends here
)
```

I know that I'm probably using exists wrong, but I know I'm on the right track since I can get the name pairs back from the `assignments` table, I just don't want back the whole column. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Yes, there are duplicates in `assignments`, and WorkEmail doesn't match all Email! I will do an update to the `assignments` email column if I can get the appropriate emails from the list that will match the first/last names in the `stafftbl` table.

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that you are missing a correlation condition in the subquery. Without it, the outer query returns all rows from `stafftbl` as soon as any row in `assignments` has an email that can be found in the list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT WorkEmail 
FROM stafftbl s 
WHERE EXISTS  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM assignments a
    WHERE 
        a.Email = s.WorkEmail     -- correlation to the outer query
        AND a.Email IN  (
            SELECT email 
            FROM (VALUES 
                ('josh@myjob.org'),
                ('pete@myjob.org'),
                ('willy@myjob.org'),
                ('linda@myjob.org'),
                ('mary@myjob.org'),
                ('james@myjob.org'),
                ('ahmed@myjob.org'),
                ('horatio@myjob.org'),
                ('luke@myjob.org'),
                ('terri@myjob.org'),
                ('chuck@myjob.org'),
                ('betty@myjob.org'),
                ('bigbob@myjob.org'),
                ('arthur@myjob.org'),
                ('Ajessica@myjob.org')
            ) E(email)
        )
)
```

Note 1: there is no need to use `DISTINCT` and to return specific columns from the `EXISTS` subquery. This expression is meant to check if the subquery returns *some record*, and the results are basically discarded. I changed it to `SELECT 1`.

Note 2: I also suspect that you don't need `DISTINCT` in the outer query (unless there are duplicate emails in `stafftbl`.

Note 3: as your query is, using table constructor `VALUES()` in the subquery is unecessary. You could just use `IN`, as:

```
AND a.Email IN  ('josh@myjob.org', 'pete@myjob.org', ...)
```

Comment: Yes, there are duplicates in `assignments`, and my problem in a nutshell: WorkEmail doesn't match all Email! I will do an update to the `assignments` email column if I can get the appropriate emails from the list that will match the first/last names in the `stafftbl`.

Comment: in a high volume of data the DISTINCT is highly inefficient ... it implements with a group by if it wants to establish a unique list of records